# selecting value of particular index with PHP foreach

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach

I have the following loop that creates an array

```
 while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1))
                    {  

                                    $aliens[] = array(

                                        'username'=> $row1['username'],
                                        'personal_id'=> $row1['personal_id']

                                );


                    }
```

It produces the following result

```
Array ( 
[0] => 
Array ( [username] => nimmy [personal_id] => 21564865 )
[1] => 
Array ( [username] => aiswarya [personal_id] => 21564866 ) 
[2] => 
Array ( [username] => anna [personal_id] => 21564867 )
```

Then I have another loop as follows, inside which, I need to fetch the personal_id from the above array. I fetch it as follows.

```
 foreach($aliens as $x=>$x_value)
            {
                 echo $aliens['personal_id'];
                //some big operations using the 
                  $aliens['personal_id']; variable

             }
```

However, I can't get the values if personal_ids. I get it as null. What seems to be the problem? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of "aliens", each alien is an array with `personal_id` and `username` keys.

```
foreach ($aliens as $index => $alien) {
  echo $alien['personal_id'], PHP_EOL;
}
```

The `foreach` loop iterates its items (aliens). The `$alien` variable represents the current iteration's item, i.e. the alien array.

Comment: $alien['personal_id'] returns null.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($aliens as $x=>$x_value)
{
    echo $x_value['personal_id'];
    //some big operations using the 
    $x_value['personal_id']; variable
}
```